# "ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could not be found." plpython3u Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, plpython

When ever I try to create extension plpython3u
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could not be found.
This message shows up I can't add extension. I am running my PostgreSQL server in windows 10

Command That I am Using 'CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u ;'
OS 'Windows 10'
PostgreSQL version '14'
Python Version '3.11.8'

I have read all similar error and I also tried below fixes

- Adding Environment variable for python
- Check python version compatibility file:///C:/Program%20Files/PostgreSQL/14/doc/installation-     notes.html directory
- tried different version of PostgreSQL 14,15,1
- verified this file exists
  -restart servers

What I am Missing ?

Objective: Seamless Integration of Python with PostgreSQL in Windows 10 using plpython3u extension

Comment: It sounds like you've made some obvious checks. Could you post the version of the library your installation requires, the version reported by the dell and the permissions for the system postgres user on that file. Also, a quick check if your antivirus logs might be in order to make sure that's not interfering

Comment: Are you using the EDB version of Postgres? If so did you install the [Language Pack](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/language_pack/latest/) and follow **all** the instructions here [Install](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/language_pack/latest/installing/windows/)?